# Embed midi(mp3, if midi not possible) files in a piano app built with HTML5

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, midi

I'm building a simple HTML5 app that will work in android, iOS and windows phone. I have designed a piano and want to embed midi files to each of the keys. Is there any way to do it using HTML5 or jQuery? The keys are in a `<ul>` tag.

Comment: The midi files are in your app or the server?

Comment: @Bojan-Kseneman midi files are in the app, not on the server

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you make a simple JavaScript interface and assign click listeners to your `<ul>`and callback the owner activity when one of them is clicked.

As far as I know, you can play MIDI files with [JetPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html), but I never tried that out myself.

MediaPlayer is also capable of playing midi according to [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/11/simple-exercise-to-play-midi-audio.html?m=1)